# Sem_post() not working correctly that is neither its increasing the value of semaphore nor unblocking the process attached to that semaphore

Tags: c, process, ipc, semaphore

sem_post() not working correctly that is neither its increasing the value of semaphore nor unblocking the process attached to that semaphore block queue

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    sem_t pa,ch;
    sem_init(&pa,1,1);  
    sem_init(&ch,1,0);

    pid_t p1;

    p1 = fork();
    if(p1>0)    //Parent process
    {
        while(1)
        {
        sem_wait(&pa);
        printf("Parent\n");
        sem_post(&ch);
        }
    }
    else if(p1==0)
    {
        while(1)
        {
            sem_wait(&ch);
        printf("child\n");
        sem_post(&pa);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("\nError\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The Expected output is

```
Parent
child
Parent
child
Parent
child
.. and so on..
```

Actual Output is

```
Parent
```

Comment: Please comment your code

Answer (score 1):

To quote `man sem_init`:

> `int sem_init(sem_t *sem, int pshared, unsigned int value);`
>
> If  `pshared` is **nonzero**, then the **semaphore is shared between processes,
>          and should be located in a region of shared  memory**  (see  shm_open(3),
>          mmap(2),  and  shmget(2)).   (Since a child created by fork(2) inherits
>          its parent's memory mappings, it can also access the  semaphore.)   Any
>          process  that  can  access  the shared memory region can operate on the
>          semaphore using sem_post(3), sem_wait(3), and so on.

Your semaphore is not in shared memory, hence the forked child process will not see any changes done in the parent process (and vice versa). Hence both processes run into a dead-lock.